# How to interact with dart debugger from the command line?

Tags: debugging, dart

Say you have a simple command-line Dart program that has a call to `debugger()` for a breakpoint. For example:

```
main() {
  print('hello');
  debugger();
  print('goodbye');
}
```

When I run the program:

```
dart main.dart
```

The console displays output up until the breakpoint and pauses in the console. However, I don't see any output from the debugger and I cannot interact with the debugger. How can I interact with the debugger from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if there are a command line tool for handling debugging but if you run your application with `--observe` your get e.g. the following output:

```
dart --observe program.dart 
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:8181/t8BNcN7MCEo=/
hello
vm-service: isolate (208832671) 'main' has no debugger attached and is paused.  Connect to Observatory at http://127.0.0.1:8181/t8BNcN7MCEo=/ to debug.
```

In the web front-end your can access the debugger by clicking on the link at "paused by breakpoint at main (program.dart:7:1) [debug]" where you have access to all the usual debugging utilities like step.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: Not able to interact with the variables. Just see these commands (`break`, `clear`, `cls`, etc`, but even they don't work as expected).

Comment: Could you tell more about what you expect of these commands? About the interaction with variables I don't think the Dart VM has support for modifying variable values from the debugger. But you can see the value of each variable in your scope.

Comment: @julemand101 looking for the equivalent of when in python, I can insert the keyword `breakpoint()` on some line, and when I run the script from the command-line, it will stop when it reaches that line and I'll have access to any variables defined before the breakpoint. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint